# Ubuntu 21.04 Failed to apply overlay '0_rpi-poe' (kernel)

Tags: kernel, raspberrypi, 21.04

I have Ubuntu 21.04 installed on a Raspberry Pi 4. I want to control the fan on the POE+ HAT (https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-plus-hat/)

By default the fan does not spin at all. When I add `dtoverlay=rpi-poe` to  `/boot/firmware/config.txt` the fan works in a seemingly default mode.
But when I do `sudo dtoverlay -l` there are no overlays loaded so I don't know why it makes a difference.

Custom settings like these do not work as expected. When I add these the fan stops completely or falls back to default mode.

```
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=50000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=58000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=64000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=68000
```

When I try to load the overlay `rpi-poe` I get the response `* Failed to apply overlay '0_rpi-poe' (kernel)` which maybe means it's not available in this kernel?
`GNU/Linux 5.11.0-1012-raspi aarch64`

Comment: What model do you have? https://uk.pi-supply.com/products/pi-poe-switch-hat-power-over-ethernet-for-raspberry-pi ? https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-hat/ ?

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/poe-plus-hat/ the POE+ hat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Ubuntu 21.04 builds for the Pi 4 with the PoE+ hat there is one slight difference that you're missing which is causing this issue. The firmware driver and associated device tree overlay is named `rpi-poe-plus`, **not** `rpi-poe` (this is for the older PoE hat).

You can find this out by seeing the available device tree overlays with the following command and noting that there are two listed.

```
ls /boot/firmware/overlays | grep poe
```

Add the following to the `/boot/firmware/config.txt` file to get the fan working with the PoE+ hat.

```
dtoverlay=rpi-poe-plus
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=80000,poe_fan_temp0_hyst=2000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=70000,poe_fan_temp1_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=65000,poe_fan_temp2_hyst=3000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=60000,poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

You can adjust the poe_fan_temp values to what you like so as to ramp the fan at different temperature values of the CPU. The values are degrees C x 1000.

Comment: awesome, thank you! also explained well. you may have forgotten the "=" after dtoverlay in the code example.

Comment: Good catch! @Thijs

Answer (score 0):

After being frustrated by the lack of documentation, I found this github project that seems to nail it:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/2715#issuecomment-769405042

rpi-poe was updated in March 2020 adding:

```
Name:   rpi-poe
Info:   Raspberry Pi PoE HAT fan
Load:   dtoverlay=rpi-poe,<param>[=<val>]
Params: poe_fan_temp0           Temperature (in millicelcius) at which the fan
                                turns on (default 40000)
        poe_fan_temp0_hyst      Temperature delta (in millicelcius) at which
                                the fan turns off (default 2000)
        poe_fan_temp1           Temperature (in millicelcius) at which the fan
                                speeds up (default 45000)
        poe_fan_temp1_hyst      Temperature delta (in millicelcius) at which
                                the fan slows down (default 2000)
        poe_fan_temp2           Temperature (in millicelcius) at which the fan
                                speeds up (default 50000)
        poe_fan_temp2_hyst      Temperature delta (in millicelcius) at which
                                the fan slows down (default 2000)
        poe_fan_temp3           Temperature (in millicelcius) at which the fan
                                speeds up (default 55000)
        poe_fan_temp3_hyst      Temperature delta (in millicelcius) at which
                                the fan slows down (default 5000)
```

Config suggested:

```
# PoE Hat Fan Speeds
dtoverlay=rpi-poe   
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0=65000   
dtparam=poe_fan_temp0_hyst=1000   
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1=70000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp1_hyst=2500
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2=80000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp2_hyst=5000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3=90000
dtparam=poe_fan_temp3_hyst=5000
```

Check if in dmesg you have an error like, then you're hitting a problem with a firmware update:

```
[...] rpi-poe-fan rpi-poe-fan@0: Failed to get default PWM value: -5
[...] rpi-poe-fan: probe of rpi-poe-fan@0 failed with error -5
```

Explanations on how to use a previous firmware in here:
https://github.com/raspberrypi/firmware/issues/1531

After you change config.txt and reboot, check that values are Ok with:

```
od -An --endian=big -td4 /proc/device-tree/thermal-zones/cpu-thermal/trips/trip?/temperature /proc/device-tree/thermal-zones/cpu-thermal/trips/trip?/hysteresis
```

You should get:

```
65000 70000 80000 90000
1000 2500 5000 5000
```

Cheers

Comment: There are 57 comments in the link to issue 1531 so I'm not sure what you refer to but I don't have the dmesg message with rpi-poe so I think it's not a firmware issue then if I understand correctly

Comment: Did the config suggested work?

Comment: no the cooler does not do anything anymore, less than using the defaults

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu 21.04.
You don't need to do anything. I just added a POE-plus to an RASPI4/8g and the fan adheres to the default settings as shown by Carlos (thanks Carlos) above.
The current version 21.04 has all you need.
Verify with:

Enter the following command:

od -An --endian=big -td4 /proc/device-tree/thermal-zones/cpu-thermal/trips/trip?/temperature /proc/device-tree/thermal-zones/cpu-thermal/trips/trip?/hysteresis

you should get:

```
   40000       45000       50000       55000
    2000        2000        2000        5000
```